# Self similar set and its measure

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Prove: If $(K,\{f_i\}_{i=1}^N)$ is a self-similar set and $(\mu,\{\mu_i\}_{i=1}^N)$ is a self-similar measures, there is any arbitrary partition $\Lambda=\Lambda_a(r_1,\cdots,r_N)$ and
\begin{equation}
\int_Ku(x)d\mu(x)=\sum_{\omega\in\Lambda}\mu_{\omega}\int_K(u\circ f_{\omega})(x)d\mu(x)
\end{equation}
where $u\in C(K)$

Comment: Is there anyone helping me prove this?                      Let $A=\{x\in K:u(x)\leq t\}$, it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_Ku(x)d\mu(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\mu(A)dt=\sum_{i=1}^N\int_0^{\infty}\mu(f_i^{-1}(A))dt\textrm{ and}\\
f_i^{-1}(A)=\{f_i^{-1}(x):x\in K,u(x)\leq t\}=\{x\in K:(u\circ f_i)(x)\leq t\}.
\end{eqnarray*} 
Consequently,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_Ku(x)d\mu(x)=\sum_{i=1}^Np_i\int_K(u\circ f_i)(x)d\mu(x)
\end{eqnarray*} 
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\int_Ku(x)d\mu(x)=\sum_{\omega\in\Lambda}\mu_{\omega}\int_K(u\circ f_{\omega})(x)d\mu(x).
\end{equation*}